# SortedMultiset which returns collection of objects (not simply count of objects)?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I want to organize a set of `Events` which have a unique `id` and a `time`. I want to efficiently query for `Events` within particular time bounds. Some `Events` might have the same `time` but different `id`.

Some `Events` might have the same `time`, so the Guava `TreeMultiSet` class is really close to what I need.

However, consider the following psudo-code snippet:

```
class Event
{
    Object id;
    long time;
}

TreeMultiSet<Event> s = TreeMultiSet.create( new Comparator<Event>( )
        {
            @Override
            public int compare( Event o1, Event o2 )
            {
                if ( o1.time < o2.time )
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if ( o1.time > o2.time )
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });

s.add( new Event( "a", 0 ) );
s.add( new Event( "b", 0 ) );
s.add( new Event( "c", 0 ) );
```

After the three additions, the `TreeMultiSet` will just contain the "a" `Event` 3 times because `TreeMultiSet` only considers the `Comparator` and the three `Event` objects have the same `time`.

My first thought was to incorporate `id` as part of my `Comparator` implementation to distinguish between `Events` with the same `time`, but my `ids` have no natural ordering (they're just `Objects` and don't necessarily implement `Comparable`).

This would also be awkward when making `subSet()`, `headSet()`, etc... queries -- I don't want the `id` of the `Event` object which I use to set the query bounds to matter.

I could implement something custom from scratch (or, more likely, delegating the heavy lifting to some underlying collections), but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something already out there which I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is TreeMultimap, though that currently doesn't support sub multi map views like you want.  That could change, though.  That said, its asMap method returns a full NavigableMap.

Comment: Hmmm... I think `TreeMultimap<TimeStamp,Event>.create( Ordering.natural(), Ordering.arbitrary() )` combined with `asMap()` does almost everything I need. My only worry is that `Ordering.arbitrary()` relies on `==` identity equality instead of `equals()`. I'll have to look into creating a similar `Ordering` using `equals()`, or is there a reason this doesn't already exist?

Comment: After looking closer at [ArbitraryOrdering](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java?r=c49086946f6bc82689d6b1d273de4e7e02091d7f#243) it looks like `==` could be replaced with `equals()` and `identityHashCode()` with `hashCode()` without problems. I wonder why `ArbitraryOrdering` wasn't implemented like to begin with.

Comment: Use `Multimaps.newListMultimap(TreeMap, Supplier<ArrayList>)` instead of coopting `Ordering.arbitrary()` like this.  (In all honesty, people using `Ordering.arbitrary()` as the value comparator to `TreeMultimap`s is a large part of the reason we're considering deprecating or deleting `Ordering.arbitrary()`.)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't happy with it, but I wasn't aware of Guava's ability to construct a custom multimap out of any provided map and collection supplier. I want set semantics (defined via `equals()`) for my values, so I'll probably end up using `Multimaps.newSetMultimap(TreeMap, Supplier<HashSet>)`. But it looks like it will work great. Thanks!